# The number keys of my computer keyboard are sometimes not working, but the numblock works

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

I'm using an updated windows 10. After a reboot my numerical keys (over the qwert.. keys ) are working and then stopping. No response and now special Characters are working. After some time they work again.

Can this be a hardware fault of my keyboard (cherry mx)?

I have absolutely no clue what is responsible for this and how I can pin down the cause. First I thought about a key logger. I tried my AntiVir from eset and SUPERAntiSpyware, but no result.

Do you have any idea or tips how to pin down the cause?

Comment: Simplest first test would be an alternative keyboard.

Comment: It works under linux, is there a tool that checks? 
Maybe I try a keylogger, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the culprit: Microsoft:[PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys)

This solved my issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/issues/760
https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/issues/410

Simple: Do not use PowerToys or use latest version.